# Magento mails / cron

Tags: email, ce-1.9.1.0, cron

I have a problem my emails from magento store not getting send, someone said I must install aoe installer and see if cron is set up correctly, I installed AOE_Scheduler it says my cron is not set up corrctly, how do I set it up ?

HELP ASAP please

None of my emails are getting send

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Magento - Wiki - How to Set Up a Cron Job](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/how_to_setup_a_cron_job)

In UNIX/BSD/linux systems you will need to add this line (or a similar line) to your crontab:

```
# for debugging purposes only:
MAILTO=your.user@your.server.com

*/5 * * * *  /bin/sh /absolute/path/to/magento/cron.sh
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could set it up in crontab like this: `*/5 * * * * wget -q http://www.yoursite.com/cron.php`